# How to prevent duplicates in reference table?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, duplicates

I have two MySQL tables:

```
tags: id / name / value
tag_groups: id / tag_id
```

tags.id is an autoincrement value. All tags are inserted individually. Here's what the result of three INSERT INTO tags looks like:

```
tags
1 "manufacturer" "Samsung"
2 "manufacturer" "Sony"
3 "manufacturer" "Apple"
```

I return each id into an array ids and create a corresponding INSERT INTO tag_groups:

```
tag_groups
1 1
1 2
1 3
```

How can I prevent tag_groups from inserting the same set of ids twice?

```
tag_groups
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 2
2 3
```

PS: If this is a known concept/problem, I apologize. I didn't know what to search for.

Comment: You should provide how you're creating the tag_groups table. Anyway, you're most likely looking for a compound primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Try using INSERT IGNORE instead of INSERT only. If a record doesn't duplicate an existing record it will insert it normally. If the record is a duplicate, then mysql will ignore your insert query silently without generating any kind of errors.

e.g.

```
mysql> INSERT IGNORE INTO person_tbl (last_name, first_name)
    -> VALUES( 'Jay', 'Thomas');
```

ref. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-handling-duplicates.htm